# Secure AJAX POST/GET jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, security

So basically my question is simple.
Imagine situation when you a making a login or register form. With jquery.post i make ajax call

```
$.post( "pages/form_handle.php", name: $.(".username").val(), pass: $.(".pass").val() , function( data ) {
$( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

it's simple call(i belive so)...

How to make it secure?
So if user look in my source code he or she know where i send my data in example **pages/form_handle.php** also he or she know what data i send to this page.
One of idea what i have simple send all ajax calls to one page **ajax.php** adding extra variables who will call right php function for ajax call...
But does it is the right way? Or maybe there is some better way to make it secure?

Comment: As long as your on HTTPS with SSL certificates it will be as safe as it gets, nobody can read your data, except for you, but what is an attacker going to do with his own password?, hack himself?

Comment: Making something secure it actually quite complicated, and requires knowledge. The real question is, how secure does it need to be? Is this is a bank, or do you store personal information? First of all, you generally don't have to worry about javascript, whatever the user can see in the source or on the screen, is data the user already know, just make sure it's not visible to everyone. On the server you should at least never store passwords, and use hashes and salts. There's millions of pages written about this, and the web is full of resources

Comment: Without https, the only real danger is man in the middle attacks, since your data isnt encrypted while inserting it, but how big is this threat exactly, when you're at home it is close to zero, unless there is some hacker on the same network as you, so lets say you're logging in on one of those crappy free wifi hotspots, if somebody is reading all the packages sent, he'll have access to the login creditentials since they're being sent as plain text via ajax, But i would insist on getting an SSL certificate as they're not that expensive.

Comment: @adeneo Does it matter? I thought we all want top secure websites no matter what info is being stored.

Answer (score 0):

**Stick to basics, and keep salting your passwords.**

AJAX is not server side language, its a javascript plugin that does the same thing as forms, actions, etc... just in background as a new request.

Your ajax is not in danger, but your php files are, you can use jquery-validate.js to check on users input, but also you should make validation check in your ajax.php.

Here is a simple ajax login request:

```
function loginUser() {
    var process = "loginUser";
    var data = $("form").serializeArray();
    data[1].value = data[1].value; // data to ajax.php page 
    data = JSON.stringify(data);

    $("#loginButton").html('Login');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {"process": process, "data": data},
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.response.state == "success") {
                // if ajax.php returns success, redirect to homepage or whatever
            } else {
                // if ajax.php returns failure, display error
            }  
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data) {
            // error handling
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

And the simple ajax.php login:

```
<?php // ajax.php

    require_once 'login.php';

    $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
    if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($db_database)
    or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());


    if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) &&
        isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])){
    $un_temp = mysql_entities_fix_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    $pw_temp = mysql_entities_fix_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$un_temp'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());

        elseif (mysql_num_rows($result)){
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            $salt1 = "qm&h*";
            $salt2 = "pg!@";
            $token = md5("$salt1$pw_temp$salt2");

            if ($token == $row[3]) echo "$row[0] $row[1] :
            Hi $row[0], you are now logged in as '$row[2]'";
                else die("Invalid username/password combination");
        } else die("Invalid username/password combination");
        }else{
            header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Section"');
            header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
            die ("Please enter your username and password");
        }
        function mysql_entities_fix_string($string){
            return htmlentities(mysql_fix_string($string));
        }
        function mysql_fix_string($string){
            if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
            return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
        }

?>
```